# angular ui-grid filter issues with MALE/FEMALE

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Im using angular ui-grid, the bottom line is that I have a 'gender' column that has "MALE" and "FEMALE". When i click the "MALE" dropdown, all MALE and FEMALE show up (obviously because m-a-l-e is in f-e-m-a-l-e).  How can I get the filter to differentiate between the two?

```
      {
        field: 'sex'
        , displayName: 'SEX'
        , width: '120'
        , editableCellTemplate: '<div><form name="inputForm"><input type="INPUT_TYPE" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" style="border-bottom-color: #74B3CE; border-bottom-width: 2px;"></form></div>'
        , filter: {
            type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
            selectOptions: [
                { value: 'male', label: 'male' },
                { value: 'female', label: 'female' }
            ]
          }
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide custom functions for filtering. Change your `column def` to have the custom filter function.

```
{
    filter: {
        type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
        selectOptions: [
            { value: 'male', label: 'male' },
            { value: 'female', label: 'female' }
        ],
        condition: customFilterSelected
      }
  },
```

and then define `customFilterSelected`

```
function customFilterSelected(function filterSelected(term, value, row, column) {
    return term === value;
}
```

this function is run everytime filter changes for each row. Parameter `term` is what the value of filter is and `value` is the value of current row. A row is show if this function returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
name: 'gender', displayName: 'Gender', enableHiding: false, resizeable: true,
filter: {
     type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
     condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT,
     selectOptions: [{ value: 'Male', label: 'Male' }, { value: 'Female', label: 'Female' }, { value: 'Other', label: 'Other' }]
}
```